# How to add color for specific word in a table

Tags: php, html, colors, html-table

My code is checking if the restaurant has a title or not and if not, the word "No Title" appears in the table. It is here I want mark the word "No Title" with red. How is that possible?

My code for that line looks like this

```
<td><?= isset($restaurant_result['title']) ? $restaurant_result['title'] : 'No Title'; ?></td>
```

Comment: do you know how to set font colours with css?

Comment: you're generating html... generate some font tags, if nothing else.

Comment: Font tags are depreciated in HTML 4 and not supported in HTML 5. Just use `<span style="[somestyles]">[sometext]</span>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a class to your `td` element:

```
<? if (isset($restaurant_result['title'])) { ?>
    <td><?= $restaurant_result['title']; ?></td>
<? } else { ?>
    <td class="no-title">No Title</td>
<? } ?>
```

And then style it with CSS:

```
.no-title {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thx, @Blender. I am stil new to html. But i have fixed it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
<td><?= isset($restaurant_result['title']) ? $restaurant_result['title'] : '<span style="color:red">No Title</span>'; ?></td>
```